# Unable to start programm `C:\Users\NAME\source\repos\Test\REST API\x64\Debug\Test REST API.exe´. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <cpprest/http_listener.h>


using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::experimental::listener;

class RestAPI {
public:
    RestAPI(utility::string_t url) : m_listener(url) {
        m_listener.support(methods::GET, std::bind(&RestAPI::handle_get, this, std::placeholders::_1));
        m_listener.support(methods::POST, std::bind(&RestAPI::handle_post, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void handle_get(http_request request) {
        http_response response(status_codes::OK);
        response.set_body("Hello from the GET request!");
        request.reply(response);
    }

    void handle_post(http_request request) {
        http_response response(status_codes::OK);
        response.set_body("Hello from the POST request!");
        request.reply(response);
    }

    pplx::task<void> open() {
        return m_listener.open();
    }

    pplx::task<void> close() {
        return m_listener.close();
    }

private:
    http_listener m_listener;
};

int main() {
    utility::string_t url = U("http://localhost:8080/api");
    RestAPI api(url);

    try {
        api.open().wait();
        std::wcout << L"Server gestartet unter " << url << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
        api.close().wait();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::wcerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXlTb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJw6O.png)

## Hi i am new here and new at C++, i am trying to make a rest api in c++ visual studio 2022. And i getting this error message "The system cannot find the file specified". I search many hours for an solution but with no succes so I hope i get help here. I tried a simple "hello world" programm while i out comment everything except the #include <cpprest/http_listener.h>, and it doesnt work. After I out comment really everything the "hello world" code worked. Sorry for my bad english